# Bizarre issue with JSON retrieval from different domain name (headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin in place and working)

Tags: jquery, json, html, header, access-control

I'm trying to create a basic test with JSON grabs cross domain....I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin in place and being recognized by the browsers, and even the JSON outputting, but for whatever reason, Jquery wont utilize the content.  No console errors, checked the network return and everything is fine...not sure what is going on.

Here is my html code:

```
<head>
  <title>Hello jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://myurlremoved:)"
      }).then(function(data) {
        $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
        $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
    <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
  </div>
```

From there, I'm merely outputting simple static JSON via a fake endpoint:

```
{"id":439,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

I've been back and forth and around on this...I'm not sure what the deal is.  Anyone see anything obvious that I'm missing?  The browser shows that the header is allowing the cross domain via the domain wildcard in the cross domain header...I'm not sure what else could be wrong...but this is new to me.

Comment: Do you get a value in the Ajax result? Try console.log. Do you get an error? Add a second function to then() to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned result a string of a json object, not an actual object. What you'll have to do is one of the following:

1. `$.getJSON` method instead of `ajax`.
2. Use `parseJSON` on the `data` variable.
3. Add `dataType: "json"` as one of the options below url in the `ajax`
   request.

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://framework.testlocker.net/endpoints/testrest.cfm",
        dataType:"json"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
            <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @matt, that was it!